# How to skip/ignore cin input

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm currently creating a C++ program to read formatted input.
The input goes into `cin` and is formatted in a txt file as follows

```
Size: (unsigned_int)
```

I'm looking for an easy way to read the unsigned_int while bypassing the "`Size:`" string in one line, which would look something like this.

```
unsigned_int size = 0;
cin >> NULL >> size;
```

Is there a trashdump/void to replace `NULL` so that the first `cin` read gets dynamically ignored and doesn't take up any extra memory?

One solution I've thought of already is having

```
string trash = ""
unsigned_int size = 0;
cin >> trash >> size;
trash = "";
```

but I'd like to avoid creating the extra variable.

Comment: Just do `cin >> junk >> size;`, where `junk` is a variable of type `std::string`.  Don't worry about the trivial amount of memory used.

Comment: There is nothing built in to the standard library that reads+discards input the way you describe, but it is trivial to write your own I/O manipulator that does, similar to what [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) does for ignoring whitespace. You just need a manipulator that ignores non-whitespace instead.